# go 1.13 has go tools version 12.9

Tags: ubuntu, go

I created the dir **TEST-13** under **GOPATH/src**

I installed **hello.go** and **hello_test.go** (the specified test code files)

Is there a reason that in version 1.13 running **go mod init**
produces the following go.mod:

```
module TEST-13

go 1.12
```

Running **go tet** in the directory gets errors - See example:

```
compile: version "go1.13" does not match go tool version "go1.12.9"
```

This message produces 7 similar messages for various library modules

How do I fix this - or is it a release error? - or did I mess up the install?

Comment: it looks likes a broken install. Please add output of `go version`, `go env`, `lsb_release -a`. Note that `go tet` is not a valid command. Did you mean `go teSt` ?

Comment: Yes -- go test!

Comment: go version go1.12.9 linux/amd64

Comment: NEPTUNE:~$go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="=/home/thornton/GO_WorkSpace/bin"
GOCACHE="/home/thornton/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""

Comment: GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/thornton/GO_WorkSpace"

Comment: GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/thornton/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/home/thornton/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"

Comment: CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"

Comment: CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build315039382=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
NEPTUNE:~$lsb_release

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
NEPTUNE:~$GOPROXY=""
NEPTUNE:~$GORACE=""
NEPTUNE:~$GOROOT="/home/thornton/go"
NEPTUNE:~$GOTMPDIR=""
NEPTUNE:~$GOTOOLDIR="/home/thornton/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
NEPTUNE:~$GCCGO="gccgo"

Comment: NEPTUNE:~$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.                                                            
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Comment: I will check hourly if you need more info - This is for work and failure is not acceptable

Comment: you can just edit your post.

Comment: have you followed this wiki to install golang ? https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu

Comment: yes - downloaded 1.13 and installed in /usr/local.

Comment: One problem:   Version in go dir 1.13

Comment: entering "go version" we get 1.12.9??

Comment: Any secret you wish to lay on me.

Comment: I just looked at your reference, it is different than the one I used which used tar to install - Will try your method

Comment: have you configured the PATH variable ? If yes, share its output (edit your initial post).

Answer (score 1):

maybe its me but, after i find versions with :

`$ where go`

and removed the ones from older versions, this issue emerged

```
# vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/internal/subtle
compile: version "go1.13.3" does not match go tool version "go1.14.4"
# vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519
compile: version "go1.13.3" does not match go tool version "go1.14.4"
# runtime/cgo
compile: version "go1.13.3" does not match go tool version "go1.14.4"
```

First I removed go again with brew too

```
$ brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies go
```

- Then I checked my path in `.bashrc` and sourced it again anyways.

It didn't solve neither.

- Finally I restarted my Terminal and it started working.

I don't know which ones were required but I can't reproduce the error. You can try all of them. If none works, maybe restart your machine as well

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by removing all traces of previous
go installations and reinstalling.

Thank you for you answers